# cmp.find(...).getElement is not a function salesforce lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

Below is my code where i am trying to create a typehead component.
But its giving error

```
cmp.find(...).getElement is not a function
```

How to resolve this issue.

component -

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" controller="AccountController" >

    <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.rxjs2}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.autoComplete}"/>
    <ltng:require scripts="/resource/Lgt_InputLookup/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js,
                /resource/Lgt_InputLookup/js/bootstrap.min.js,
                /resource/typeahead" 
                  styles="/resource/Lgt_InputLookup/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <aura:attribute name="accounts" type="Account[]"/>

    <form class="slds-form--stacked">
        <div class="slds-form-element">
            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="name">Name</label>
            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                <ui:inputText aura:id='atcmplbox' class="slds-input" updateOn="keyup"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-form-element">
            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="email">Email</label>
            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                <input id="email" class="slds-input" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="slds-form-element">
            <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" type="button">Update</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <datalist id="acctlist">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.accounts}" var="account">
            <option value = "{!account.Name}"/>
        </aura:iteration>
    </datalist>

</aura:component>
```

Controller -

```
({
    autoComplete : function(cmp, event, helper) {

        helper.autoComplete(cmp);

    }
})
```

helper -

```
({
    autoComplete: function(cmp) {

        var self = this;
        var test = cmp.find('atcmplbox');
        console.log(cmp.find('atcmplbox').getElement());
    }
})
```

Render -

```
({
    afterRender : function(cmp,helper){
        return this.superAfterRender();
    }
})
```

Comment: what you want do accomplish by finding element. you cannot find element for other namespace component

Answer (score 3):

Your `atcmplbox` is a `ui` component, what makes it part of the `ui` namespace.

```
<ui:inputText aura:id='atcmplbox' class="slds-input" updateOn="keyup"/>
```

So `find()` will not return a public `SecureComponent`, but a `SecureComponentRef`.

You won't have access to it's Element since SecureComponentRef is not providing these methods. [Read this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_global_access.htm) to understand why this is happening.

These are the different methods, first `SecureComponent` second `SecureComponentRef`

[image][image]

Some Code in case you want to play around:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <div aura:id="div" />
    <lightning:input aura:id="input" name="input1" label="Enter some text" />
</aura:application>

({
    doInit : function(cmp, evt, helper) {
        console.log(cmp.find("div"));
        console.log(cmp.find("input"));
    }
})
```

Comment: So is there any way to access it like using attribute or any ?

Comment: Yes, you are right, see my updated answer to check the available methods for `lightning:input` for example